# Printing out an AttributedString

Tags: java, javafx

I am using an attributed string to bold the heading names, and I would like to print out in a `Text` object in javafx, but I cannot figure out how. I've looked a fair amount of places online, including the java docs but nothing seems to go over this... Here is what I am trying to do:

```
AttributedString boldName = new AttributedString("Name: ");
boldName.addAttribute(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TextAttribute.WEIGHT_BOLD);

String name = innerNode.name;

Text info = new Text(**boldName.something()?** + name);
```

The result should be this: **Name:** *name*, something quite simple I feel but how??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the AttributedString in JavaFX. Instead use,

On JavaFX 2.2 and earlier:

```
Text name = new Text("Name: ");
name.setFill(Color.BLUE);
name.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
Text info = new Text(innerNode.name);
HBox hbox = new HBox(1);
hbox.getChildren().addAll(name, info);
```

On JavaFX 8:

```
Text name = new Text("Name: ");
name.setFill(Color.BLUE);
name.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
Text info = new Text(innerNode.name);
TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow(name, info);
```

Reference:
[Using Text and Text Effects in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/text/jfxpub-text.htm)
[javafx.scene.text.TextFlow](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html)